# How to see if a button in JColorChooser was chosen and how to assign that to text in a different window?(Java)

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcolorchooser

I have a java program and I want to create a color chooser that when selected saves that color and sets it to a JLabel, button, background etc. How can i get it? Here is the code below

```
public class ColorChooser extends JFrame {
    private JLabel sampleText = new JLabel("Label");
    private JButton chooseButton = new JButton("Choose Color");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ColorChooser();
    }

    public ColorChooser() {
        this.setSize(300, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        sampleText.setBackground(null);
        panel1.add(sampleText);

        chooseButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel1.add(chooseButton);

        this.add(panel1);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(//INSERT CODE HERE){
                //Set the color
            }
        }
    }
```

What would I need to put in to replace //INSERT CODE HERE in order for it to register it and how will I be able to access that and replace //Set the color?

Comment: Store the result and provide a getter of some kind.  You might also want to have a look at [How to Use Color Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at [How to Use Color Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html), which has a number of examples.

First, you need to preset the chooser to the user...

```
Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(this, "Choose", null);
```

Next, you need to test to see if the resulting `color` is `null` or not (`null` meaning the user canceled the dialog for some reason)

```
if (color != null) {
    //... apply changes...
}
```

Finally, you apply the changes...

```
sampleText.setForeground(color);
chooseButton.setBackground(color); // This might not do what you think it does
```